# Display all records from the current date - 1 in Hive

Tags: string, date, hadoop, hue

I have a column called snapshot_date that is of string type. I would like to display all the records from the table in Hadoop where snapshot_date - 1.

Sample snapshot_date '2021-06-05' (which is the current date - 1). I am posting this on 06-06-2021.
I would like to display all the rows where snapshot date is current date - 1. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use date_sub(current_date, 1) in the where clause, it is not working.
I tried from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(snapshot_date , 'dd-MM-yyyy')) also, dint work.